# Mixing borax and shampoo

Tags: everyday-chemistry, surfactants, smell

I use borax to clean everything. the other day I thought it would be a good idea to mix a little borax with my shampoo while showering.  After lathering it on my scalp about 30 seconds it began to give off a really bad chemical smell, almost like a perm solution. What was the borax reacting with the product in my hair or the shampoo?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: Every type of shampoo have slightly something different